# column is adjusting the height of the image (bootstrap, data from json)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

My pages is generating images comes from JSON file so I call it trough js file, but it display different hegiht, i want every column adjust to the height of the image so there is no gap. Especially data with category=design in json is having a long height than category=website.

HTML is in the javascript file because it will loop in every data in json

```
$.getJSON('JSON/projects.json', function(data) {
        let projects = data.projects;
        let content = '';
        jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
        $.each(projects.reverse(), function(i, data) {
            if (data.category == category.toLowerCase()) {
                content += '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3" id="project-img"><a href="img/project/'+ data.img +'"data-lightbox="myproject" data-title="'+ data.caption +'"><img src="img/project/'+ data.img +'" alt="'+ data.caption +'" class="img-fluid"><br><br><a id="button2" href="'+ data.linkProject +'" target="_blank">Open This Project ></a><a id="button2" href="'+ data.linkDocumentation +'" target="_blank">Open Documentation ></a></a></div>';
            }
        });

        $('#project-list').html(content);
    });
```

I ecpecting column adjust to the height of the image so there is no gap

Comment: This has to do with HTML/CSS. You can adjust your grids to align as such.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp
It might be a good start.

Comment: I assume since you are using Bootstrap grids, only the widths will be equal or proportioned as stated in your class. But instead you can try to centeralize using class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"

Comment: thank you @MustafaOzbalci, I have added align-items-center justify-content-center and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can like this.

Script:

```
$.each(projects.reverse(), function(i, data) {
        if (data.category == category.toLowerCase()) {
            let contentItem = '<div class="img-container" id="project-img-'+ i +'"><a href="img/project/'+ data.img +'"data-lightbox="myproject" data-title="'+ data.caption +'"><img src="img/project/'+ data.img +'" alt="'+ data.caption +'" class="img-fluid"><br><br><a id="button2" href="'+ data.linkProject +'" target="_blank">Open This Project ></a><a id="button2" href="'+ data.linkDocumentation +'" target="_blank">Open Documentation ></a></a></div>';
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
              content = content + '<div class="images-wrapper">' + contentItem;
            } else {
              content = content + contentItem + '</div>';
            }
            
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
.img-container: {
    width: auth;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.images-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    ...
}
```